# Change the path of a symlinked directory in NGINX

Tags: nginx, symlink, assets

Lets say that I have a directory /var/www/assets/ and within that directory I have a symlink which points to a folder which contains all the latest asset files for my website.

/var/www/assets/asssets -> /var/www/website/releases/xxxxxxx/public/assets

If I configure NGINX to serve asset files from /var/www/assets with the domain assetfilesdomain.com and asset files are prefixed with the directory /asset/ then when that /asset folder's symlink is changed then the updated link is not reflected in NGINX. The way that I see it, NGINX grabs the resolved path for that asset folder when it is started.

Is there any way to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reloading nginx (sending a HUP signal to the master process) seems to solve this issue (probably because it starts new workers and shuts down the old ones, gracefully).

it seems like you're using Capistrano. You can override deploy:restart and put the nginx reloading there.

Comment: Yeah the way that I see it, its best to stick to using the same folder, but just restart the mongrel/unicorn worker. Thank you.